# Randomly generate genomic positions with constraint on number of mutations per gene and sample

Tags: r, position, permutation, simulation

Let say I've a list of genomic positions harboring mutations. Each mutation is linked to one gene and one sample. My dataset looks like this :

```
chrom    pos   gene sample
chr1    1000    ABC S1
chr1    1500    ABC S2
chr1    1000    ABC S3
chr2    5000    XYZ S1
chr2    5000    XYZ S2
chr2    6000    XYZ S1
chr3    500     MNO S1
```

My goal is to generate a similar simulated mutation table where the number of mutation per sample (across all genes) and the number of mutation per gene (across all samples) is the same as the reference mutation table (the one above). In this case :

```
Gene :
ABC : 3
XYZ : 3
MNO : 1

Sample :
S1 : 4
S2 : 2
S3 : 1
```

In addition to this I've a gene table as :

```
gene    chrom   start   end
ABC      chr1   500     1100
ABC      chr1   1300    1600
ABC      chr1   2000    2500
XYZ      chr2   4000    5500
XYZ      chr2   5800    6500
MNO      chr3   200     300
MNO      chr3   400     600
MNO      chr3   800     1000
```

The idea will be to only pick positions in these intervals to generate the simulated mutation table. Size of the mutation table ~50K ; genetable ~200K

Example of simulated mutation table :

```
chrom   pos    gene sample
chr1    600     ABC S1
chr1    1400    ABC S1
chr1    1500    ABC S2
chr2    4500    XYZ S1
chr2    6200    XYZ S1
chr2    6400    XYZ S2
chr3    900     MNO S3
```

you observe that number of mutation per gene and sample are the same as in the reference mutation table.

My first idea was to first pick X_i random positions in the genes using the gene table ; where X_i = number of mutation for gene i the reference mutation table . Then assign to each of these positions a sample respecting the number of mutated samples in the reference mutation table.

In R :

```
res <- 
    refmut %>% 
    group_by(gene) %>% 
    summarise(nmut=n()) %>% # compte number of mutations per gene
    right_join(gene.table) %>% # right join with gene table
    mutate(size = end-start + 1) %>% # compute size of each gene interval
    group_by(gene) %>% 
    sample_n(size=nmut,replace = T,weight = size) %>% # Randomly sample rows, proportional to the length of each range
    rowwise() %>% # for each row
    mutate(pos=sample(start:end,size=1)) %>% # Randomly sample uniformly within each chosen range
    ungroup() %>% # globally
    mutate(sample=sample(refmut$sample)) %>% # permute samples across positions
    select(-nmut,-start,-end,-size,chrom,pos,gene,sample) # format result
```

In my code some lines may be computed before the simulation e.g. interval size and the right_join ; to go faster.

Any other idea ?

reproducible dataset :

```
structure(list(chrom = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", 
"chr2", "chr3"), pos = c(1000L, 1500L, 1000L, 5000L, 5000L, 6000L, 
500L), gene = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ", "MNO"
), sample = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S1", "S2", "S1", "S1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

structure(list(gene = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "MNO", 
"MNO", "MNO"), chrom = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", 
"chr3", "chr3", "chr3"), start = c(500L, 1300L, 2000L, 4000L, 
5800L, 200L, 400L, 800L), end = c(1100L, 1600L, 2500L, 5500L, 
6500L, 300L, 600L, 1000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 2):

The main thing I see is `rowwise`. There will be 50,000 groups in your original table, each calling `sample`. That's a lot of looping.

The alternative is to use `runif()` to produce your random numbers at once and normalizing. Specifically:

`start+as.integer(runif(n()) * (size-1))`

Full code:

```
refmut %>% 
  count(gene, name = 'nmut') %>% #different - no faster
  right_join(gene.table)%>%
  mutate(size = end-start + 1) %>% 
  group_by(gene) %>% 
  sample_n(size=nmut,replace = T,weight = size)%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(pos = start + as.integer(runif(n()) * (size-1)), #different - should be faster
         sample = sample(refmut$sample))

# A tibble: 7 x 8
#  gene   nmut chrom start   end  size   pos sample
#  <chr> <int> <chr> <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <chr> 
#1 ABC       3 chr1   2000  2500   501  2176 S1    
#2 ABC       3 chr1    500  1100   601   966 S3    
#3 ABC       3 chr1    500  1100   601   807 S2    
#4 MNO       1 chr3    200   300   101   200 S2    
#5 XYZ       3 chr2   5800  6500   701  6368 S1    
#6 XYZ       3 chr2   5800  6500   701  5871 S1    
#7 XYZ       3 chr2   4000  5500  1501  5309 S1
```

Comment: How many genes are there? Are there a lot of genes with just 1 sample?